# Stata: how to duplicate observations?

Tags: stata

I have a series of transactions that each indicate how much units were purchased. For example, I have

- Bud Light      3 units      30 cents per ounce
- Miller Light    2 units      23 cents per ounce

I want to duplicate Bud Light 3 times and Miller Light 2 times:

- Bud Light      1 unit      30 cents per ounce
- Bud Light      1 unit      30 cents per ounce
- Bud Light      1 unit      30 cents per ounce
- Miller Light    1 unit      23 cents per ounce
- Miller Light    1 unit      23 cents per ounce

In other words, I need to create as many single purchase entries as how many purchases were made as indicated in one of my columns.

How can I do that? Appreciate any input.

Comment: This question seems off-topic for this site. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. `help expand` should solve your problem.

Comment: Agreed that this is not appropriate for SO. Ask further questions on Statalist.

Comment: This tremendously helped. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a **command** that does exactly that.

Look at `expand`

Description

```
expand replaces each observation in the dataset with n copies of the observation, where n is equal to the
required expression rounded to the nearest integer.  If the expression is less than 1 or equal to missing,
it is interpreted as if it were 1, and the observation is retained but not duplicated.
```

Comment: Helpful expansion of @Roberto Ferrer's comment from 2014, but in Stata terms `expand` is a command, not a function.